What is the cardinality of $\operatorname{Add}(\lambda, \kappa)$ for $\kappa < \lambda$?
I am reading the proof of the theorem 6.17 (in the chapter VII page 215) of the Kunen's Book (the old edition), that says:

Theorem 6.17: In $M$, assume that $\lambda < \kappa$, $\lambda$ is regular, $2^{<\lambda} = \lambda$, and $\kappa^\lambda = \kappa$. Let $\mathbb{P} = Fn(\kappa \times \lambda, 2, \lambda)$. Then $\mathbb{P}$ preserves cardinals and if $G$ is $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $M$ then $(2^\lambda = \kappa)^{M[G]}$.

where:
$$\mathbb{P} = Fn(\kappa \times \lambda, 2, \lambda) = \operatorname{Add}(\lambda, \kappa) = \{ p \mid p \text{ is a partial function } \lambda \times \kappa \to 2 \text{ and } |p|<\lambda \}$$
at the begin of the proof it says that, in $M$, $\mathbb{P}$ has cardinality $\kappa^{<\lambda}$ (and hence using the hypothesis over $\kappa$: $|\mathbb{P}| = \kappa$).
I'm trying to prove this claim but I can only prove that $|\mathbb{P}| \ge \kappa^{<\lambda}$ because for every subset $D$ of $\kappa \times \lambda$ with size less than $\lambda$ I can consider the function $f: D \to 2$ such that $f(d) = 1 \ \forall d \in D$ and there are $(\kappa \times \lambda)^{<\lambda} = \kappa^{<\lambda}$ many sets like this. How about the other inequality?

You can't really say much about the continuum function in general.

What do you mean? :-|

Think about separating into evens and odds. Given $p:D\subseteq\kappa\times\lambda\rightarrow 2$ we can consider the set $$Set_p=\{(2\alpha,2\beta): p(\alpha,\beta)=0\}\cup\{(2\alpha+1,2\beta+1): p(\alpha,\beta)=1\}.$$ Crucially, the map $p\mapsto Set_p$ is injective. Meanwhile, if $p\in\mathit{Add}(\kappa,\lambda)$ then $Set_p$ "is" (= can be coded by) an element of $\kappa^{<\lambda}$.
